# How to use .ltx as extension for LaTeX documents?

Tags: latex, auctex

Usually I name my LaTeX files using the extension `.ltx` like `file.ltx`. How can I configure Emacs+AUCTeX in a way that it recognizes those files and load AUCTeX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your init file:

```el
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.ltx$" . latex-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

The regular expression says "ends with `.ltx`". 
Documentation is [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html#Choosing-Modes).